# Rename in scope doesn't work as expected in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In the attached source file in RStudio, when I go to the menu option Code > Rename in Scope, I would have expected all instances of df to be selected, but only the first instance is selected. Anybody know why all instances are not selected?

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? What if you use the shortcut (Ctrl/Cmd + Alt + Shift + A)?

Comment: same happens to me, it does not seem to recognise a script as a scope. It works within a function.